# how to unset the item in $_SESSION array

Tags: php, session, unset

i have 2 functions. First one is adding item to cart, second should delete specific item based on product id.

```
function AddToCart($pid) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['products']['prod_count'])) {
        $_SESSION['products']['prod_count'] ++;
        $incart = $_SESSION['products']['prod_count'];
        $_SESSION['products'][$incart]['product_id'] = $pid;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['products']['prod_count'] = 0;
        $incart = $_SESSION['products']['prod_count'];
        $_SESSION['products'][$incart]['product_id'] = $pid;
    }
}

function DeleteProduct($pid) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $key => $my_value) {
        foreach ($my_value as $key => $product_id) {
            if ($product_id == $pid) {
                // do not know how to unset this product
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need some idea on how to unset the product if $product_id == $pid or may be some other ideas how to achieve that.

My array look something like:

```
array(1) { ["products"]=> &array(4) 
                { ["prod_count"]=> int(2) 
                           [0]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(4)}
                           [1]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(10) } 
                           [2]=> array(1) { ["product_id"]=> int(11) } } }
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, because to be honest you should reconsider how do you store cart. Won't be eaysier if you store it like this: `$_SESSION['products'][$product_id] = $qty` ?

Comment: It seems you have some unnecessary parts to your array, why are you storing a product count when you could easily do `count()` and you are also manually incrementing your array with this value when you could use use `[]`.   Edit: I agree with @Peter

Comment: use `unset` with the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would simply solve your problem:

```
    function DeleteProduct($pid) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $key => $product) {
            if ($pid === $product['product_id']) {
                unset($_SESSION['products'][$key]);
            }
        }
    }
```

But to make your work alot easier in the future you could also build your array like this:

```
$_SESSION['products'] = array(
    'product_id' => 'amount',
);
```

To add a product you would simply do:

```
$_SESSION['products'][$product_id] += $amount;
```

To count your products you could use:

```
count($_SESSION['products']);
```

Here is a simple example of what your functions could be like:

```
function addProduct($pid, $value = 1) {
    $_SESSION['products'][$pid] += $value;
}

function removeProduct($pid) {
    unset($_SESSION['products'][$pid]);
}

function countProducts() {
    return count($_SESSION['products']);
}
```

Good luck!